# Using if on height prop in vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have some card with height prop for height ofc..
I need to have different heights for xs and higher sizes so I did this:

```
<v-card height="250"> --> works

<v-card :height="[$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 450 : '250']">
```

And I get error that says, number or string expected got array.

For other things like `:class, :style` etc works fine...

Comment: You were returning `[]` array with one value (450 or 250) and it was expecing a string. Instead of `:height="[$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 450 : '250']"`, you should write it without `[]`. Like this `:height="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 450 : '250'"`. But I would go with the answer and create the `computed` property :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a computed property to return the height like :

```
  computed:{
       getHeight(){
            return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 450 : '250';
          }
     }
```

and inside template :

```
<v-card :height="getHeight">
```

if you don't want to use any property you could use it by removing the brackets like :

```
  <v-card :height="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 450 : '250'">
```

Comment: I know that works, if I have 100+ different values I need 100+ different computed or one method with switch case but I would like to know why it doesnt work within prop like for other things

Comment: i did that and you could learn more about breakpoints [`here`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/framework/breakpoints#breakpoints)